# Checking a database value per 5 seconds is expensive with a lot of user count like 10000 or more?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, server-side, client-side

I'm programming a multiplayer RPG game using Unity, and in battle scene, player has to determine which attack she or he uses. When the player presses attack button, player sends a post request to the server and server makes the mandatory checks if post request is legal or not, then if request is legal, server flags a database value "on", or to be exact, makes it "1" from "0", that is called "attack_determined", for example.

The problem is, I have to make http request again to check this value. There are maximum 6 characters on a battle and if all of the people want to check if attack_determined is 0 or 1, it makes 6 requests per attack request. And I don't want to think if user count is increased to 10000 for example. It would be so hard to handle these requests for the VPS server I'm using. Is there any way to decrease request count? I don't want to use sockets, I was thinking to use sessions or memcache. I'm using PHP for the server side, and C# for the Unity client side.

Comment: This just seems like a really bad way to design something interactive.

Comment: I agree to @DavidSchwartz you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: Web sockets is *an appropriate approach* if you have something web-like (which might be an in-browser UI, or might be a client app that uses http rather than a dedicated socket protocol). It scales very well for what you're trying to do (and much higher; our web-socket server currently has 450k open connections). Http poll every few seconds: would kill us instantly. If you combine all your other traffic onto the same web-socket: even better.

Comment: use UNET its simple make script of different variable and minus or add through command and rpc functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't want to use sockets

Use WebSockets.

You can use [websocket](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) standalone library or use Unity's Network API and enable websocket on it. If you decide to use Unity Network API, this can be enabled by simply setting [`NetworkServer.useWebSockets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer-useWebSockets.html) to `true`.

Once enabled, Unity will switch from socket to websocket. If you are just working on WebGL app, you can take a look at this websocket plugin on the [assetstore](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38367).